# Understanding event.target.elements

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using javascript (React, but I don't think this is specific to React) to handle a form submit. None of my elements are controlled, and I'd like to keep it that way. I may not know beforehand exactly what the form elements are, how many there are, etc. I just want to grab whatever is in the form and send it wherever it needs to go.

I'm doing some logging in the event handler so I can inspect `event.target.elements` and it's a bit confusing. It seems to look like both an indexed array and an object at the same time, with each form element getting a numeric entry and a named entry. It has a `length` property equal to the length of the number of numeric entries (ignoring the named entries), but if I try to use a `.forEach` directly on it, I get the error `event.target.elements.forEach is not a function`. If I use `Object.entries` to loop over it, both the numeric and the named entries are logged. But if I use `lodash` to loop over it, I just get the numeric entries.

I'd just like to know what exactly is going on. If `event.target.elements` is not an array, why does it have a `length` property? If it is an array, why can't I use a regular `forEach` directly on it?

My form submit event handler looks something like this, for testing/learning purposes:

```
let handleSubmit = async( event ) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("event.target.elements",event.target.elements);
  console.log("event.target.elements",typeof event.target.elements);

  Object.entries(event.target.elements).forEach(([name, input]) => {
     console.log("name",name);
     console.log("input",input);
  });

  console.log("------");

  _.forEach(event.target.elements, (el,key)=>{
     console.log("key",key);
     console.log("name",el.name);
     console.log("value",el.value);
  });
}; // handleSubmit
```

And the output is below, note that the `Object.entries` loop executes four times, whereas the `lodash` loop executes twice

```
event.target.elements HTMLFormControlsCollection(2) [input, select, test2: input, test1: select]
    0: input
    1: select
    length: 2
    test1: select
    test2: input
    __proto__: HTMLFormControlsCollection
event.target.elements object
name 0
input <input type=​"hidden" name=​"test2" value=​"asdf">​
name 1
input <select name=​"test1">​…​</select>​
name test2
input <input type=​"hidden" name=​"test2" value=​"asdf">​
name test1
input <select name=​"test1">​…​</select>​
------
key 0
name test2
value asdf
key 1
name test1
value 3
```

Comment: It is a reference to formElem.elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the answer is in your code example: it is an `HTMLFormControlsCollection` ([MDN entry here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)).

In JS it's not only `Object`, `Array`, `Map` & `Set` (OK, `WeakMap` & `WeakSet`), but there are other types (collections) too, like the "family" of `HTMLCollection`s.

These all have their specialties & can be used in different use-cases, but they can be used as `Array`s with some iteration-techniques:

```js
const inputForm = document.getElementById("input-form")

inputForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const el = e.target.elements
  console.log("el.toString():", el.toString())
  console.log("instanceof HTMLFormControlsCollection:", el instanceof HTMLFormControlsCollection) // expected: true
  console.log("instanceof Array:", el instanceof Array) // expected: false

  // iteration #1
  // using map() on collections
  const mapped = Array.prototype.map.call(el, (ele) => ele)
  console.log("mapped:", mapped)

  // iteration #2
  // logs the elements
  for (let ele of el) {
    console.log("for...of:", ele)
  }

  // iteration #3
  // logs the keys of the HTMLFormControlsCollection
  for (let ele in el) {
    console.log("for...in:", ele)
  }

  // iteration #4
  const spread = [...el]
  console.log("spread:", spread)
});
```

```html
<form id="input-form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```